# how to do filter/query on in-memory list/map using guava

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have complex objects

```
    class Person{
        Integer id;
        String fname;
        String lname;
        //..... there are more attributes
        List<Address> addresses;
    }
    class Address{
        String street1;
        String street2;
        String city;
        String state;
        String zip;
    }
```

I have about **30000 Person** objects and each has at-least **200-500 sub object (addresses)**. Now I have all these in-memory and i have different scenarios (20-30 scenarios) where i have to query/filter objects based on filters available in scenarios. For eg.

- scen1 -> get all object having lname = 'zoik'
- scen2 -> get all object having lname = 'smark' and address.street1 = "xyz"
- scen3 -> get all object having lname = 'smark' and address.street1 = "xyz" and address.street1 = "pqr" (remember each object has multiple address so i need object which has both address which satisfy above condition.)
- scen4 -> get all object having fname= "smith" and lname = 'smark' and address.city="Los Angeles"
- .....

In short, there are multiple scenarios with different combination of both the objects.
Please advice the best way to utilize Guava for such case?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Iterables.filter(Iterable, Predicate)` in conjuction with `Predicate`s.

Example:

```
public class PersonLastNameEqualsPredicate implements Predicate<Person> {
  private String personName;
  public PersonNameEqualsPredicate (String personName) {this.personName= personName;}
  public boolean apply(Person p) { return this.personName.equals(p.getLName()); }
}

public class PersonStreet1EqualsPredicate implements Predicate<Person> {
  private String street1Name;
  public PersonStreet1EqualsPredicate (String street1Name) {this.street1Name = street1Name;}
  public boolean apply(Person p) {
    for (Address a: p.getAddresses()) {
      if (street1Name.equals(a.getStreet1()) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

// Extra predicates as you need them
```

You need one predicate per scenario item. Then you need to modulate them as you need them:

1.

```
Predicate<Person> peopleNamedZoik = new PersonLastNamePredicate("zoik");
```

2.

```
Predicate<Person> peopleNamedSmarkAndLivingInXyzStreet = Predicates.and(new PersonLastNamePredicate("smark"), new PersonStreet1EqualsPredicate("xyz"));
```

3.

Here you should adapt your street predicate to check at once if all street names contain all your expectation.

Then it's simply a matter of

1.

```
List<Person> myLongPersonList = ...;
Iterable<Person> zoikPeople = Iterables.filter(myLongPersonList, peopleNamedZoik);
```

2.

```
List<Person> myLongPersonList = ...;
Iterable<Person> zoikPeople = Iterables.filter(myLongPersonList, peopleNamedSmarkAndLivingInXyzStreet);
```

And so on.

Comment: thank you for your reply. 
just one question, while applying predicates i dont want to iterate to 30K object each time when i apply predicate. is there any way i can build map/index while iterating first time and then just query those objects on while processing them?

something like 
        step 1:  build index(s) or map(s)
        step 2:  myFilteredObjects = someListOrMap.get(scenarioDef)
        

I am not much familiar with Guava so may be expecting a lot from it :D, feel free to correct me.

thax a lot.

Comment: premature optimization?  Are you sure you care?  30000 is not really a lot of iteration, especially if they are already in memory

Comment: @rst: you get a lazy iterable so at that moment nothing is actually iterated yet. You can then use other temporary collections to actually iterate and store them. Use preferably guava's static constructors like Lists.newArrayList(Iterable) because they support getting iterables.

Comment: Why would you not build a complex predicate?